# How to remove application that is "not installed"?

Tags: 12.04, uninstall, games

Ubuntu 12.04.3 64-bit.

Installed app "Implosion" from Software Center. Tried it out, and removed it via Software Center. But it is still installed and playable! Reinstalled from SC and removed again, but same result.

```
Sudo apt-get remove/ purge implosion says implosion is not installed. 

dpkg -L implosion says implosion is not installed.
```

I cannot locate implosion-files in `/usr/bin`. System says it's not there, but it is!

How do I find it and remove it?

Comment: What is the output of `locate implosion` command?

Comment: Yes, probably it would be in your `home` directory.. Try to locate in your home directory and remove it.. After removing try these commands : `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get autoclean` Hope after that you would not be able to play with that.. :P ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try these commands:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/info/implosion*
sudo apt-get purge implosion*
```

If that doesn't work, you could try:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file    # apt-file is used to list installed files
sudo apt-file update
sudo apt-file list implosion
```

Then deleting all of those listed files


Note: I was unable to find the package `implosion` in the default repos of 13.04, though it appeared in the software centre